# What uses does the Bat With Attitude have?

Tags: fallen-london

In Fallen London, I have acquired a Bat With Attitude; it was the result of a rare success on the *Parliament of Bats* opportunity card. It's a pet with exactly zero bonuses, and the description says

> Fidgeting and unco-operative, but charmingly leathery, and it has its
>   uses. Don't ask.

I've had this bat for quite some time (I've even become a Person of Some Importance in the meantime), and have yet to see it be even *mentioned* in storylets. I shall tempt fate, and *ask:* aside from its high sell price (12.5 Echoes), does it have any other uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having searched both wikis, become a Person of Some Importance, and wandered most (but not quite all) of the game, I can say that there are no story uses for the Bat With Attitude. It sells for 12.5 echoes, which is quite good for the circumstances where you can pick it up.

So: it's [vendor trash](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VendorTrash).